# How to find the first elements with a specified class

Tags: javascript

Let I've an HTML markup. How can I find the first element with an appropriate class (e.g. I want to find all `div`s with class `myclass`).

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div.classname')` or when you only need the first hit ``document.querySelector('div.classname')``

Comment: all elements or first element?

Comment: Oh come on, This is [basic DOM manipulation / access.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName(yourClass)[0]
```

`document.getElementsByClassName(yourClass)` gets all of the matching elements in an array, `[0]` gets the first.

For older IEs:

```
var match, i = 0,
    divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
while(!match && divs[i]) {
    if(divs[i].className.match(yourClass).length) {
      match = divs[i];
    } else {
     i++;
    }
}
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('.yourClass')`

Should return first instance of the matched selector